# SSIS 2014 Project deployment

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am using Project deployment model for SSIS 2014.  I have deployed once and configured all configurations to project level and Package level. Now I need to make a change to only one project and need to deploy only this change. I am not using Environments but on prod I made configuration changes manually. Now I just want to deploy this project for which I made only some script task changes nothing changed to project/package configuration level. If I deploy this project now  I have to make all this configurations again on production.
What’s the best way to deploy only this project without touching production configurations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're fine, just deploy.

Here I have a project and configured it, no environment reference, to a value of 2. You can tell this because it's bold

[image]

I redeployed my project and there's a timestamp of 5 minutes ago

[image]

I recheck my configurations and they're still there

[image]

Deploying an ispac puts it into table A. Applying a configuration sets values in table B. The only action you can take that would force you to redo all the configurations is if you deleted the existing project and then re-added it because then the internal project number would change.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and if I had couple of changes to project or package params in this deployment will it append those change with leaving current configurations untouched?